# How to use system in Cocoa to invoke curl

Tags: cocoa, curl, system, file-upload

I was wondering the best way to upload file to a web server in cocoa. I cant seem to get my curl code to work even though it works when run from terminal.

curl code:

```
system(@"curl -T /file.txt http://webserevertouploadto.com")
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I suspect that `system()` does not take an NSString, since it's not cocoa.  As PCWiz says, NSTask is the cocoa way to make calls like system().

Comment: `system` works just fine in Cocoa; in fact, it works no differently: You need to pass a C string to it, just as you would without Cocoa. But NSTask is better than `system`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/index.html) instead of system() to execute curl. If you're looking for a native Cocoa solution for uploading files via FTP, take a look at [ConnectionKit](http://opensource.utr-software.com/connection/download.html).

Answer (score 3):

One negative of using curl is that it won't respect the user's proxy settings.

I prefer to use the NSURLConnection API.

Check this out:
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUploadSample

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it seems like a lot of code just to upload a file when you can use curl in only a few lines.

Comment: happyCoding: You missed the first paragraph of the answer. “curl… won't respect the user's proxy settings.” You can tell curl to use a proxy, but you'd still have to get the proxy settings to give to it, and then it's not “only a few lines” anymore.